# JSON parsing independent of JSON structure

Tags: json, gson

Every time response JSON structure changes, parsing logic of JSON needs a change. I am wondering is there a way to avoid this or some alternative ?

In other words, it means parsing JSON without knowing the structure, is it possible ?

Comment: if you don't know the structure, how do you want to use it?

Comment: One option is to parse it as Map if the structure is unknown.